# Keras' equivalent to Tensorflow's matmul function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm new to Keras and I can't seem to find an equivalent to Pytorchs bmm function or Tensorflows matmul function.

What would be the closest equivalent to this in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keras.backend.dot`

From the documentation:

> Multiplies 2 tensors (and/or variables) and returns a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Backend functions simply point back to their tensorflow/theano sources and cannot be used as is. To use them you need to wrap them into a Lambda layer:

```python
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras import backend as K
# this is simply defining the function
matmul = Lambda ( lambda x: K.dot(x[0], x[1]) )
# this is applying the function
tensor_product = matmul([tensor1, tensor2])
```

Not wrapping backend functions into Lambda layers will result in `TypeError`. Alternatively you can use the `Dot` layer which computes the dot product across an axis of your choice:

```python
from keras.layers import Dot
tensor_product = Dot(axes=-1)([tensor1, tensor2])
```

Comment: Should I not be using "matmul = Lambda ( lambda x: K.matmul(x[0], x[1])" ?

Comment: where did you find matmul?

Answer (score 0):

Tecnically.. I think the direct equivalent to tf.matmul is **K.batch_dot**. this way you do not use the batch dimension.